# gdal2tiles syntax error

Tags: gdal, gdal2tiles

I'm attempting to produce tiles for a tif with the following call to gdal2tiles.py:

```
gdal2tiles.py --profile=raster C:\Users\kcwil\media\bmng_qsc\0\frontside.tif
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
gdal2tiles.py --profile=raster C:\Users\kcwil\media\bmng_qsc\0\frontside.tif
                               ^
```

"C:\Users\kcwil\media\bmng_qsc\0\frontside.tif" is a valid file produced by gdalwarp.
As I understand it, gdal2tiles takes its parameters in the form : [options] input_file [output_dir] and what I am doing appears to be similar to examples I've seen.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to run `gdal2tiles.py` from a python prompt. Run it from a command line prompt.

How you do that depends on your operating system and how you installed GDAL.  If using windows, you may (depending on how you installed GDAL) need to prepend the command with the correct python interpreter and the full path to `gdal2tiles.py`,

Comment: Thank you! Now I'm just missing some modules.